# How to split dataframe column containing json array?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

How to split below column into expected output using python split function?
I have already used json_normalize and stored it into dataframe.
In dataframe it created one column languages under which below value is stored.

```
    languages
    [{'name': 'French', 'vowel_count': 3}, {'name':'English', 'vowel_count': 5}]
```

expected output:

```
   name                vowel_count 
 French                3  
English                5
```

Json file I used:

```
data1=[{
 "languages" : [
    {
        "name" : "French",
        "vowel_count" : 3
    },

    {
        "name" : "English",
        "vowel_count" : 5
    }

  ]}]
```

I have already used:

```
json_normalize(data1,'languages')
```

but I want it to use only

```
json_normalize(data1)
```

which generates

```
    languages
    [{'name': 'French', 'vowel_count': 3}, {'name':'English', 'vowel_count': 5}]
```

and split generated column into multiple columns.

Comment: What is reason not use `json_normalize(data1,'languages')` what working very nice?

Comment: I want to automate the normalization task without providing any header to json_normalize. Is it possible to get it from user?

Comment: Can you explain more `Is it possible to get it from user?` ?

Comment: @jezrael I am dropping that idea. Is it possible to split                             
 [{'name': 'French', 'vowel_count': 3}, {'name':'English', 'vowel_count': 5}] without giving column name in json_normalize. Actually I am writing generic code to convert json into dataframe. So I don't want it to be dependent on column name.